# Error creating bean Spring with name while deploying My Application on Wildfly 14

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, wildfly

Hi am migrating my spring application from jboss 6 to wildfly 14.
I'm using Spring version 3

The application was deplyed with no issu in Jboss 6, When I tried de deploy it in Wildfly 14 I got the this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationSessionListener' defined in "/C:/Produits/LDEV-BACK/wildfly-14.0.1.Final-EXA/bin/content/muses-web.war/WEB-INF/classes/fr/bdf/muses/manager/ApplicationSessionListener.class": Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010041: The servlet context has already been initialized, you can only call this method from a ServletContainerInitializer or a ServletContextListener:
```

Is it possible de deploy a spring 3 application on Wildfly 14 ? If yes can someOne please guides me to resolve this.

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>catalogue-archive.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/erreur/403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/erreur/405.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>408</error-code>
        <location>/erreur/408.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/erreur/default.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>MYAPP USERS</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/lib/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/erreur/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/login-page.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/logout.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/auth.html</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>MYAPP USERS</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AUTHENTICATED_RESOURCE</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method-omission>OPTIONS</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>MYAPP admin</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AUTHENTICATED_RESOURCE</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin-MYAPP/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>superviseur</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA1416</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA1416</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA2113</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA2113</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA1482</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA1482</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA2504</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA2504</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA2109</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA2109</role-name>
            <role-name>AU_MYAPP_RSP</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>MYAPP debug</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AUTHENTICATED_RESOURCE</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/debug-MYAPP/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>superviseur</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA2109</role-name>
            <role-name>FU_UA2113</role-name>
            <role-name>FU1UA2113</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU1UA2113</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU1UA1416</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU_UA2109</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU1UA2109</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU_UA2113</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU_UA1416</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU1UA1482</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU_UA1482</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU1UA2504</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>FU_UA2504</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>AU_MYAPP_RSP</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ldapm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/loginController.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/erreur/auth.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>tff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-tff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- <filter> <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name> <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param> <param-name>configuration</param-name> <param-value>${muses.wro4j.profile}</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>gzipResources</param-name> <param-value>FALSE</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cacheUpdatePeriod</param-name> <param-value>60</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>modelUpdatePeriod</param-name> <param-value>600</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>jmxEnabled</param-name> <param-value>false</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>disableCache</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param> </filter> -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is myApp-servlet.xm file

```
<beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
    
    <import resource="classpath*:/data-access-config.xml" />
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.sg.myApp"/>
    
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />
    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
    <bean id="sessionListener" class="fr.sg.myApp.manager.ApplicationSessionListener"></bean> 
    
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="fr.sg.myApp.manager.CurrentUserInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptors> 
    
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

And here is my Bean Spring

```
@Component
public class ApplicationSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener,
        ApplicationContextAware {
    
    private static int totalActiveSessions;
    
    @Autowired
    private ReportService reportService;
    
    public static int getTotalActiveSession() {
        return totalActiveSessions;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        totalActiveSessions++;
        
        HttpSession session = arg0.getSession();
        Date now = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
        reportService.createSession(session.getId(), now);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        totalActiveSessions--;
        
        HttpSession session = arg0.getSession();
        Date now = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());
        reportService.updateSession(session.getId(), now);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        if (applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext()
                    .addListener(this);
        } else {
            // Either throw an exception or fail gracefully, up to you
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Must be inside a web application context");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you are not loading your spring context in a way for it to register your HttpSessionListener with the container

Comment: Have you actually read the error? You cannot register a listener that way. The context is already initialized (the servlet-context) and you cannot modify it afterwards. Instead this listener should be defined in the `web.xml` as a regular listener and you should pull the dependencies from the application context instead of injecting them.

Comment: I added the listener in my web.xml                                                                 
 <listener>
        <listener-class>fr.sg.myApp.manager.ApplicationSessionListener</listener- 
         class>
 </listener>                                                                                                                                     But I still get the same exception